# SQL developer connection password forgot

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new here so I might not be able to give the exact detailed information about the problem but here we go.I had a connection made as system in sql developer.I forgot the password so I thought I could solve it by deleting it.But when I reinstalled it,the connection stays the same and didn't get deleted.Now I can't access the database or write any queries.
The error code is ORA-12505.

Tried reinstalling,Making new connection.
I am hoping to delete that connection and make a new one.